# Can the EC2 metadata API return objects?

Tags: windows, powershell, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

Is it possible to get objects back from the instance metadata API or do you always have to point to what you want directly?

```
# So I could do this:
$obj = Invoke-Restmethod -uri http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/
$obj.placement.availability-zone
$obj.hostname

# Instead of this:
$zone = Invoke-Restmethod -uri http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/placement/availability-zone
$name = Invoke-Restmethod -uri http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/hostname
```

Its easy enough without objects, but just curious if its possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the `/latest/dynamic/` path. The exact URL is:

```
http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document
```

It returns a JSON of the following form:

```
{
  "devpayProductCodes" : null,
  "privateIp" : "172.31.1.178",
  "availabilityZone" : "us-east-1c",
  "accountId" : "XXXXXXXXXXX",
  "version" : "2010-08-31",
  "region" : "us-east-1",
  "instanceId" : "i-XXXXXXXXXX",
  "billingProducts" : null,
  "instanceType" : "t2.micro",
  "pendingTime" : "2016-10-20T16:16:48Z",
  "imageId" : "ami-XXXXXXXX",
  "architecture" : "x86_64",
  "kernelId" : null,
  "ramdiskId" : null
}
```

Note that it does not have `hostname` field (and a few others which can be accessed via `meta-data` call), but it does have quite a lot of information.